# Pandas DataFrame read_csv then GroupBy - How to get just a single count instead of one per column

Tags: pandas, dataframe, count

I'm getting the counts I want, but I don't understand why it is creating a separate count for each data column.  How can I create just one column called "count"?  Would the counts only be different when a column as a Null (NAN) value?

Also, what are the actual column names below? Is the column name a tuple?

Can I change the groupby/agg to return just one column called "Count"?

**CSV Data:**

```
'Occupation','col1','col2'
'Carpenter','data1','x'
'Carpenter','data2','y'
'Carpenter','data3','z'
'Painter','data1','x'
'Painter','data2','y'
'Programmer','data1','z'
'Programmer','data2','x'
'Programmer','data3','y'
'Programmer','data4','z'
```

**Program:**

```
filename = "./data/TestGroup.csv"

df = pd.read_csv(filename)
print(df.head())

print("Computing stats by HandRank... ")
df_stats = df.groupby("'Occupation'").agg(['count'])
print(df_stats.head())

print("----- Columns-----")
for col_name in df_stats.columns:
   print(col_name)
```

**Output:**

```
    Computing stats by HandRank... 
                 'col1' 'col2'
                  count  count
    'Occupation'              
    'Carpenter'       3      3
    'Painter'         2      2
    'Programmer'      4      4

----- Columns-----
("'col1'", 'count')
("'col2'", 'count')
```

The df.head() shows it is using "Occupation" as my column name.

Comment: should nans be included? are you looking for `df_stats = df.groupby("'Occupation'").size().reset_index(name='Count')` ? count by default doesnot count `NaN`

Comment: `df['Occupation'].value_counts().to_frame(name='count')`.

Comment: @QuangHoang - Why didn't you put that as an answer, instead of a comment?  I like it a little better, because it does not leave the column name in the resulst df_stats.    I had to change to: df_stats = df["'Occupation'"].value_counts().to_frame(name='count') (It's using the quotes from the CSV so the fieldname includes the quotes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `size`

```
df_stats = df.groupby("'Occupation'").size().to_frame('count')
```

Comment: Thanks, that works great!  Any idea why my attempt and you answer both leave the 'Occupation' (column header) in the df_stats?  Doesn't it know that's a column name, so why would it include it in the count?  By default, I think read_csv uses first line for column name.

Comment: @NealWalters that is index name , so you can add df_stats.rename_axis(None)